# Delegated value throwing error on create - Rails 5.2.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a `Order` that is the child of a `User`. I want to be able to set the `tax_exempt` attribute on `User` via my `create_quote` form. I have added the following delegates to my `Order` model:

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user

    delegate :tax_exempt, to: :user, prefix: true
    delegate :tax_exempt=, to: :user, prefix: true
end
```

When I submit my form (on create) I get the following error:

```
Module::DelegationError (Order#user_tax_exempt= delegated to user.tax_exempt=, but user is nil:
```

I have verified and `user_id` is not `nil` and is submitted in my params. Even from my controller when I force the user with the following code, I still get the same error:

```
order = User.first.orders.create(parameters)
```

The operation does however work on edit. I don't understand why I cannot set the attribute of my parent `User` via the delegate. Thanks in advance.

**Update**

The following code produces the same error from rails console:

```
User.first.orders.build(tax_exempt: true).save!
```

Going a step further and making sure that the `User` isn't overridden somewhere for some unknown reason I attempted the following code which again still produced the same error:

```
User.first.orders.build(tax_exempt: true, user_id: User.first.id).save!
```

Comment: First, is there a `user_id` being passed via `parameters`? Second, what happens if you do `User.first.orders.build(parameters).save!`?

Comment: mentioning stack versions is always helpful

Comment: Can confirm this bheavior on rails 4 and 5 both, and https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/33154 suggests it should be an active issue. Try to get this re-opened.

Comment: Also note this wont save your updates to user model, unless you have set `auto_save` option to true, both in create and update cases.

Comment: @ZiaUlRehmanMughal I'm on Rails 5.2. Thanks for the help, I up-voted your request on git. Hopefully we can get somewhere with this.

Comment: While new and than doing new_obj.user_tax_excempt = 'xyz' works, i would say just avoid delegates for updates and just use it for reads. For updating associated records, rails way is to use accets_nested_attributes_for not delegations.